# Is this a Zener Diode? UPDATE it just turned into dust :( phone still turns on, what the...? O_o

Tags: diodes, zener

my Nexus 4 usb connection died and when opening it I found a burnt component which looks like a zener diode, it could be a transistor though, I need help identifying this component so I can replace it.

Here's a picture:
[image]

Thank you!

EDIT:

The TVS just burnt completely off, it turned into dust. Phone still turns on though... what's the worst that could happen?

Comment: It's not a transistor with only 2 leads

Comment: Can you either post a closeup of the top, or see if you can read a device code?  (Maybe letters and/or digits)

Comment: Sorry I meant to say resistor.

Comment: That component doesn't look burnt to me (i.e. no charring). How did you determine that it was "burnt"? ...could be just my eyes though :)

Comment: Oh that's a stock image. The one in my phone completely turned into dust, just checked :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a 9.0V transient voltage suppressor. Vishay and Diodes list it as bidirectional and Littelfuse lists it as unidirectional, however both Vishay and Diodes state that the bidirectional device has no polarity marking therefore it is most likely unidirectional.

Comment: Why did it blow though? Bad charger or battery? Where can I buy it?

Comment: Too much power. Any of the big online retailers will have a replacement.

Comment: Have a link? :( Kinda flying blind.

Comment: http://www.newark.com/ http://www.mouser.com/ http://www.digikey.com/

Comment: How many Watts?

Comment: I couldn't say. It may be that other parts are faulty though, and that's what caused this in the first place.

Comment: The phone still charges, but it won't connect to the PC. Turns on and everything, it says USB Descriptor Failed. What would happen if I just short it?

Comment: The normal operation of a TVS is open, not shorted.

Comment: The TVS just turned into black powder :( phone still works and charges, no PC connection though.